# cocos2d-x adMob ad does not load

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-x

Adding adMob to my Cocos2d-x project.

In my onCreate in my main activity I have:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId("MY AD UNIT ID");

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
          Log.d("xxx", "onAdClosed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
              Log.d("xxx", "onAdFailedToLoad");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
              Log.d("xxx", "onAdLeftApplication");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
              Log.d("xxx", "onAdOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
              Log.d("xxx", "onAdLoaded");
        }
      }); 

    // Create ad request.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("MY TEST DEVICE ID").build();

    // Begin loading  interstitial.
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

None of the logs are logging and when I call `interstitial.isLoaded()` every 10 seconds it always returns `false`.

NB : `MY AD UNIT ID` and `MY TEST DEVICE ID` are set appropriately

So, basically, I can't get an ad to load and I can't get it to tell me that it didn't load.  I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly, I missed a step in the getting started guide and failed to have this

`<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`

in my AndroidManifest.xml.  Live and learn.